# Downloading files from sftp newer than x date with ruby

Tags: ruby, sftp, ruby-2.0

I need to download new files over sftp each night. There are currently thousands upon thousands of files within this directory (which I have no control of), and would like to be able to limit the files that I have to grab to whatever is newer than the last time I ran this process.

I know that I can do this over ssh fairly easily, however I haven't seen a way to do this with sftp only. Do I have any options other than iterating over each file and checking the attributes.mtime?

example:

```
Net::SFTP.start('sftp.host.com', 'username', :password => 'password') do |sftp|
  sftp.dir.glob('prefix.', '*').each do |file|
    if Time.at(file.attributes.mtime) > last_process_time
      sftp.download!(file, "some/local/path/")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The (obvious) comparison with rsync (which is over ssh, but.. duh):

Your code only compares timestamps, rsync also checks for filesize and optional checksum. It also creates file lists on both sides and compares them. Then it starts to transfer the files that are not in sync. Not sure if rsync uses multiple simultaneous file downloads. And rsync probably does a lot more smart things. ([source](http://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html))

Perhaps some of those rsync characteristics can be used to build a faster sync system using sftp only. Multiple simultaneous downloads looks like an instant win to me.

Can you compare your sync time results with rsync times (create a dev setup if needed)? Because I think once you got some of the above things in place, what remains is some overhead of the sftp protocol.